# angular-tree-component creating a context menu

Tags: angular, contextmenu

I have successfully found how to initialise a context menu on the angular-tree-component

```
const actionMapping: IActionMapping = {
  mouse: {
    contextMenu: (tree, node, $event) => {
      $event.preventDefault();
      alert(`context menu for ${node.data.name}`);

    }
  },

};
```

but i can't find any documentation on how to actually build and display a menu. So how would I, for example, display a context menu of 2 items {Action A, Action B) with click events for each item?

thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

So you initialized the context menu by implementing IActionMapping interface. Now you need to add it to options like

```
 options: ITreeOptions = {
    actionMapping
 };
```

Then include options in the component's input like

```
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options"></tree-root>
```

Refer to the documentation [here](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/options)
and an example [here](https://github.com/CirclonGroup/angular-tree-component/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/actions/actions.component.ts)

In order to build an actual context menu you can see an example [here](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/create-custom-context-menu-in-angular-efeae0137e1a)